# I'm trying to implement a trench navigation program in JavaScript, but can't quite get the parts to detect T-shaped branches working right

Tags: javascript, matrix, graph, navigation, nodes

I've got the code to find the neighbors of specific matrix nodes (north, south, east, west) working fine, and while some features of my functions to traverse trenches and identify trenches are working well, I'm still having issue with detecting T-shaped branches that should result in these functions returning false values.

Here's my full program code.

```
// Function to find neighbors
function findNeighbors(node, matrix) {

    // Results array
    const res = [];

    // Current row
    const row = node[0];

    // Current column
    const col = node[1];

    // North, if row is greater than zero
    if (row > 0) {

        // Set matrix coordinate as a northern value
        const nVal = matrix[row - 1][col];

        // If deeper than -5, push
        if (nVal < -5) res.push([row - 1, col]);

    };

    // South, if row less than matrix height
    if (row < matrix.length - 1) {

        // Set matrix coordinate as a southern value
        const sVal = matrix[row + 1][col];

        // If deeper than -5, push
        if (sVal < -5) res.push([row + 1, col]);

    };

    // East, if column less than matrix height
    if (col < matrix[0].length - 1) {

        // Set matrix coordinate as an eastern value
        const eVal = matrix[row][col + 1];

        // If deeper than -5, push
        if (eVal < -5) res.push([row, col + 1]);

    };

    // West, if column creater than zero
    if (col > 0) {

        // Set matrix coordinate as western value
        const wVal = matrix[row][col - 1];

        // If deeper than -5, push
        if (wVal < -5) res.push([row, col - 1]);

    };

    // Return neighbors
    return res;

};

// Function to traverse trenches
function trenchTraversal(node, matrix, visited) {

    // Get coordinates of node passed in
    const [row, col] = node;

    // If node depth less than -5, return false
    if (matrix[row][col] >= -5) return false;

    // Set stack equal to node passed in
    const stack = [node];

    // Add node passed in to visited set
    visited.add(node);

    // Path array
    const pathArr = [];

    // While the stack has length
    while (stack.length) {

        // Get current node from stack
        const current = stack.pop();

        // Push current node to path array
        pathArr.push(current);

        // Set current coordinates to the current node
        const [currentRow, currentCol] = current;

        // Get current node value from matrix
        const currentNode = matrix[currentRow][currentCol];

        // Find neighbors of current node
        const neighbors = findNeighbors(current, matrix);

        // Loop through neighbors
        neighbors.forEach(neighbor => {

            // Get neighbor coordinates
            const neighborCoord = [neighbor[0], neighbor[1]];

            // If the visited note doesn't have neighbor coordinates
            if (!visited.has(neighborCoord)) {

                // Push the neighbor onto the stack
                stack.push(neighbor);

                // Add neighbor coordinates to visisted set
                visited.add(neighborCoord);

            };

            // Check if trench is T-shaped
            if (!visited.has(neighbor[0] - 1 && neighbor[1] - 1)) return false;

        });

        // If the path is three or more nodes long, return true
        if (pathArr.length >= 3) return true;

    };

    // Return false
    return false;

};

// Function to identify trenches
function identifyTrench(trenchMatrix) {

    // Create set to hold visited coordinates
    const visited = new Set();

    // Loop for rows
    for (let i = 0; i < trenchMatrix.length; i++) {

        // Inner loop for columns
        for (let j = 0; j < trenchMatrix[0].length; j++) {

            // If the coordinate is deeper than -5
            if (trenchMatrix[i][j] < -5) {

                // If a valid trench exists, return true
                if (trenchTraversal([i, j], trenchMatrix, visited)) return true;

                // Else return false
                else return false;

            };

        };

    };

    // Return false if no valid trenches are found
    return false;

};

// Local test

// // Example 0
const sonar_0 = [
    [-5, -5, -5],
    [-6, -5, -8],
    [-5, -7, -5]
]

// Log neighbors of coordinates
console.log(findNeighbors([1,1], sonar_0)); // => Expect [[2, 1], [1, 0], [1, 2]];

// Initialize visited nodes set
const test_visited = new Set();

// Add to visited nodes test set
test_visited.add([2, 1]);

// Traverse trench with test node
console.log(trenchTraversal([0, 1], sonar_0, test_visited));

// First matrix example
const sonar_1 = [
          [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5],
          [-5,-8,-8,-9,-7],
          [-5,-5,-5,-5,-8],
          [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5]
];

// Log whether trenth in in matrix
console.log(identifyTrench(sonar_1)) // <- Expect 'true'

// Second matrix example
const sonar_2 = [
          [-5,-5,-5,-7,-5],
          [-5,-8,-8,-9,-5],
          [-5,-5,-5,-7,-5],
          [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5]
];

// Log if second matrix has trenches
console.log(identifyTrench(sonar_2)) // <- Expect 'false'

// Third matrix example
const sonar_3 = [
          [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5],
          [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5],
          [-5,-9,-9,-5,-5],
          [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5]
];

// Log if third matrix has trenches
console.log(identifyTrench(sonar_3)) // <- Expect 'false'
```

I'm having particular issue with this portion of the code to detect T-shaped branches.

```
// Check if trench is T-shaped
if (!visited.has(neighbor[0] - 1 && neighbor[1] - 1)) return false;
```

The second and third examples should return false, but they return false true values.

I've tried code such as this to detect more than two neighbors:

```
if (visited.size > 2) return false;.
```

But it doesn't work, either and yields the same results.

I changed some of the code to this:

```
const neighborCoords = [];

        neighbors.forEach(neighbor => {

            neighborCoords.push([neighbor[0], neighbor[1]].toString());

        });

        // Loop through neighbors
        neighborCoords.forEach(neighborCoord => {

            // If the visited note doesn't have neighbor coordinates
            if (!visited.has(neighborCoord)) {

                // Push the neighbor onto the stack
                stack.push(neighbors[neighborCoord]);

                // Add neighbor coordinates to visisted set
                visited.add(neighborCoord.toString());

            };

            // Check if trench is T-shaped
            if (visited.has(neighborCoord[0] - 1 && neighborCoord[1] - 1)) return false;

        });

        // If the path is three or more nodes long, return true
        if (pathArr.length >= 3) return true;

    };
```

But now I get this new error:

```
const [currentRow, currentCol] = current;
                                         ^

TypeError: current is not iterable
```

Even though I wasn't getting it before.

Comment: One problem is that visited.has(neighborCoord) for example can never be true, since you just created that neighborCoord array.  It doesn't matter that the contents of your neighborCoord array match some other array in the set, it's not the *same* array and it won't find it.

Comment: I tried console.logging my visited set, but it doesn't seem anything's being added to it at all, for some reason.

Comment: I edited my programming code with some new things I tried.